# Why would MessageQueue.Send(x) fail silently on a local private queue?

Tags: c#, msmq

My application uses a local private `MessageQueue(@".\private$\queuename")` to sequence messages from its multiple threads, and has been doing so successfully for a long time. Recently, an error occurred that caused several of those messages to essentially disappear without a trace. From the app's internal logging and the eyewitness account, it seems that the `Send(msg)` method failed to place the message into the queue and raised no error. In a debugger, I simulated that scenario by having execution skip the `Send()` call, and the resulting log info matches what was logged in the actual error occurrence.

Most disturbing is that the error condition existed for 45 minutes, persisting through a computer reboot and application restart, and required a second restart after the reboot to finally clear it.

[This unresolved post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118717/what-would-cause-msmq-to-place-messages-destined-for-queues-on-the-local-system)[^] hints that the message might end up some place other than the intended local queue. Unfortunately, all evidence of it that might have existed was gone by the time I was able to inspect the system where the error occurred. I considered using the `TimeToReachQueue` acknowledgement to detect failure of the `Send()` call, but MSDN asserts [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.defaultpropertiestosend.timetoreachqueue?view=netframework-4.7.2)[^] that "If the queue is local, the message always reaches the queue," although this event challenges that claim.

Recurrence of this error will be a serious problem, so if I can't prevent it, I need to be able to detect and report it. Not knowing what actually happened makes both options extremely difficult.